# Gridview textbox filter - Paging NOT working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, textbox

Im working in my app, with a gridview with sorting and filtering, users needs a filter for more specific filter, I'm using a javascript filter and It works, but when the gridview has 2 pages or more, it filters only first one.

**This is the javascript filter:**

```
<!-- Gridview Filtro -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%=lblNoRecords.ClientID%>').css('display','none');

    $('#<%=Button1.ClientID%>').click(function(e)
    {
        $('#<%=lblNoRecords.ClientID%>').css('display','none'); 
        $("#<%=gvwSacBus_Docs.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").hide(); // Hide rows.

        var iCounter = 0;
        var sSearchTerm = $('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').val(); //search value

        if(sSearchTerm.length == 0) //all rows if textbox empty
        {
          $("#<%=gvwSacBus_Docs.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").show(); 
          return false;
        }
        //Iterate 
        $("#<%=gvwSacBus_Docs.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").children().each(function() 
        {
            var cellText = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            if(cellText.indexOf(sSearchTerm.toLowerCase()) >= 0) //Check matches
            {    
                $(this).parent().show();
                iCounter++;
                return true;
            } 
        });
        if(iCounter == 0)
        {
            $('#<%=lblNoRecords.ClientID%>').css('display','');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    })
})
</script>
```

**The app works with layers, this is for get data:**

```
public List<Cajas> Cajas_Buscar_CajaXCont(string clienteCodigo, string cajaContenido)
{
    List<Cajas> ListCajasxContenido = new List<Cajas>();
    string storedProcedure = "CAJAS_BUSCAR_CAJAXCONT";

    using (DbConnection con = dpf.CreateConnection())
    {
        con.ConnectionString = conStr;
        using (DbCommand cmd = dpf.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = storedProcedure;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            DbParameter param1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
            param1.DbType = DbType.String;
            param1.ParameterName = "CLIENTE_CODIGO";
            param1.Value = clienteCodigo;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

            DbParameter param2 = cmd.CreateParameter();
            param2.DbType = DbType.String;
            param2.ParameterName = "CONTENIDO_CAJA";
            param2.Value = cajaContenido;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

            con.Open();
            using (DbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //creamos un objeto de tipo Caja, y por c/ registro encontrado en la db, insertamos
                        Cajas cajaBus = new Cajas();

                        cajaBus.ClienteCodigo = dr["CLIENTE"].ToString();
                        cajaBus.CajaCodigo = dr["CODIGO CAJA"].ToString();
                        cajaBus.CajaNumero = Convert.ToInt16(dr["NUM"].ToString());
                        cajaBus.CajaContenido = dr["CONTENIDO"].ToString();


                        if (Convert.IsDBNull(dr["F.EMI"].ToString())) //para manejar los valores DBnull
                        {
                            cajaBus.FecEmisionDoc = Convert.ToDateTime("9999-01-01"); //de lo contrario c# no los podra interpretar
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cajaBus.FecEmisionDoc = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["F.EMI"]);
                        }

                        ListCajasxContenido.Add(cajaBus);
                    }
                    catch (System.InvalidCastException)
                    { }
                    catch (System.FormatException)
                    { }
                }
            }


        }
    }
    return ListCajasxContenido;

}
```

**And I call te data on presentation:**

```
protected void sacbus_Consul_Cajas_x_Cont()
{
    gvwSacBus_Docs.DataSource = null;
    gvwSacBus_Docs.DataBind();
    gvwSacBus_Docs.DataSource = cajaBL.sacbus_Consul_Cajas_x_Cont(lbl_SacBus_CliCod.Text,
                                                        txt_SacBus_Criter.Text);
    gvwSacBus_Docs.DataBind();

    if (gvwSacBus_Docs.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "AlertScript", "alert('No Encontrado!');", true);
    }

}
```

**This is the textbox for filtering**

```
<asp:TableRow
                                    ID="TableRow2"
                                    runat="server"
                                    BackColor="OrangeRed">
                                    <asp:TableCell>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                                    </asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:TableCell>
                                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  />
                                    </asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:TableCell>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblNoRecords" Text="No records to display" runat="server" ForeColor="red"></asp:Label>
                                    </asp:TableCell>
                                </asp:TableRow>
```

**And this is my grid (uses ItemTemplates)**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvwSacBus_Docs" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" 
                                AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" Font-Size="Small"
                                AllowPaging="true" PageSize="100" OnPageIndexChanging="gvwCajNuev_PageIndexChanging" 
                                AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gvwSacBus_Docs_Sorting">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID = "chkAll_cajas" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  
                                                OnCheckedChanged="chkAll_cajas_CheckedChanged" />
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCaja" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <a href="#" onclick="window.open('Cajas_Historial.aspx?cliCod= <%#Eval("ClienteCodigo").ToString() 
                                                + "&cajCod=" + Eval("CajaCodigo").ToString()
                                                + "&cajNum=" + Eval("CajaNumero").ToString()
                                                %> ','PrintMe','height=500px,width=1300px,scrollbars=1');">Hist</a>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CLIENTE">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID = "lblSacBus_CliCod" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClienteCodigo") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="COD.CAJA">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID = "lblSacBus_CajCod" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CajaCodigo") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

etc
etc
etc

As you can see, My problem is with te paging on filterig, I hope anyone please can help me.

best regards...

Answer (score 0):

`GridView` pages on the server (ASP.Net) side even though your stored proc gets all the data. Since you are filtering by hiding records on client side, it's limited to the current page. I suggest you filter the data on the server side (Even better for performance if you can filter it in your stored proc / DB) and provide the result to `GridView` to properly filter.